# Does someone know of 'iPaper-secure'-like service?

Tags: security, pdf, scribd, ipaper

I've been using Scribd secure and their javascript/PHP api for few years. I've made a custom upload page where I upload books and automatically disable printing/downloading/copying, because this is what my client wants. Those books are then embedded into a page on my site.

I was never really satisfied with Scribd API and their 'iPaper secure' because it is not really secure but I wasn't able to find better solution for displaying documents to registered members while restricting save/copy/print. And Scribd developer support was very bad. But I lived with that.

Unfortunately, I just noticed that printing is no longer disabled on my 'secured' documents, because Scribd removed this option almost 3 years ago, without my knowledge :)

Please, does anybody know of any way for me to host books 'securely'?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are several PDF to html converters which would allow you to put the content on your site (with full control) or you could use something like PDF.js to display files.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, however I am now trying to use Google Books, still not sure whether it will work for me...